# What is the maximum number of rows a DataGridView can render OK?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview

I wonder what the maximum number of rows a `DataGridView` can render OK is, I mean the UI is usable and responsive enough. I want to know this because I have a table of about 1400 rows (not now but it will be so in the future), I wonder if it can render OK or I should load rows partly with supporting some navigation controls.

PS: I don't need the exact number, just the number from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: winforms doesn't support too much data. If you need a lot of rows in a DataGrid I suggest you use WPF which has built-in UI Virtualization, therefore supports much bigger datasets without having any performance impact.

Comment: @HighCore I'm interested in `Winforms` and my question is some kind of Yes or No, so if you experienced enough, just answer it but to be sure, I ask this question but I believe 1400 rows are not too many for a DataGridView to render OK.

Comment: `IMO`, winforms is useless and deprecated so my answer is no you can't do anything of value with it in 2013. If it was 1990 maybe I would consider it an option. Though maybe other people will tell you otherwise

Comment: The Winforms DGV also supports virtualization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx). If you find that performance suffers due to the amount of data, you can leverage it.

Comment: @HighCore you are talking about the time of 10 years later. `Winforms` has not been deprecated yet, many people are using it. You won't never believe that even `VB6` is still used by some of people. And I bet, `Winforms` is still useful in many kinds of application. At least, to learn it, any newbie won't spend much time to get started while `WPF` is another thing.

Comment: @KingBoy a newbie doesn't do an application that loads 1500+ records of data. Please name a use case where you will choose a horrible, non-customizable, non-scalable, too-much-code-for-everything, fond of horrible hacks (owner draw, P/Invoke), software rendered UI technology from 20 years ago instead of current stuff.

Comment: @Tergiver You supposed if I feel there is some issue with the performance, but at the moment, my data has not enough rows to feel. Adding rows myself doesn't reflect exactly the performance because there are some other factors including data binding, cell-formating,...

Comment: You should not write any application without testing it fully, under all supported conditions.

Comment: @HighCore `WPF` is just a very advanced level programming interface, P/Invoke is just low-level, you can't get rid of the base if you want to understand everything deeply. I think you may hate `Assembly` so much, but I love `Assembly` forever.

Comment: @KingBoy go ahead and show me something like [this](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) done purely in assembly language, or even winforms. No one cares about low-level implementation details, we need something that allows us to do our applications, rapidly, and make them look good and current, not some horrible UI that looks like windows 3.1

Comment: @HighCore I'm feeling that you even want to refuse the existence of 0 and 1 bits. I don't think `WPF` was built totally from scratch without inheriting any `Windows-stuff including Windows Messages`,....

Comment: @KingBoy don't make me repeat myself. I DON'T CARE about the low level implementation details. I care about the fact that WPF allows me to do useful usable beautiful data-driven applications, while winforms doesn't support 1400 rows in a datagrid.

Comment: @HighCore I've just tested myself (with 2000 rows and 10 columns, each cell value is just a GUID) and I feel it's acceptable. OK enough to use.

Comment: @KingBoy then you've answered your own question. Go ahead and [try with 20000](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA).

Comment: @HighCore wow, great. I don't refuse the performance of WPF, however the control in the video is not DataGridView. Anyway thanks for the video.

Comment: @HighCore just tested with 20000 rows and it made me surprised that there was no much difference (in loading time and responsiveness) compared with the case of 2000 rows. That's great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested with 20000 rows of 10 columns and it seems that the UI is OK and responsive enough, the loading time is just about 300ms. When I tried with only 1 column, the loading time was nearly immediately. Not like in this video:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA (the control in the video is not DataGridView however).

Here is the testing code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
}    
for (int j = 0; j < 200000; j++)
{
   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
   for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
   {
      row[k] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Now I can feel free to use my DataGridView to hold 1400 rows (in the future).